# URL Builder in Swift

Tags: swift

I am newbie on Swift and I am building API URL string as follows before pass it to URLSession.

I wonder there is a better way of doing it?

```
let jsonUrlString = Constants.API_URL + "/" + Constants.PATH + "/" 
                    + String(page)+"/" + Constants.NUMBER_ITEMS_PER_PAGE
```

Comment: Your current way is fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to build a URL is to use `URL` and `URLComponents`. Simply appending strings together is error prone and it does not properly escape special characters that you might have in your values.

Here's one possible solution using `URL`:

```
if let baseURL = URL(string: Constants.API_URL) {
    let jsonURL = baseURL.appendingPathComponent(Constants.PATH)
                         .appendingPathComponent(String(page))
                         .appendingPathComponent(Constants.NUMBER_ITEMS_PER_PAGE)
    // use jsonURL with your URLSession
}
```

Another option with `URLComponents` (this properly ensures special characters are encoded):

```
if let baseComps = URLComponents(string: Constants.API_URL) {
    var components = baseComps
    components.path = "/\(Constants.PATH)/\(page)/\(Constants.NUMBER_ITEMS_PER_PAGE)"
    if let jsonURL = components.url {
        // use jsonURL with your URLSession
    }
}
```

Comment: `components.url` is getting nil??

Comment: I forgot the leading `/` in the path.

Comment: Ok now it is working, I wonder which one do you prefer to use `URL` or `URLComponents`? Which one is commonly used among the developers? Readibility perspective, the URL option is looks better compared to URLComponents.

Comment: Use the one that works properly. The use of `URLComponents` is much better when you need to build a URL from parts that need to be encoded properly, especially when the URL will need a query string.

Comment: how do you handle if URL is not valid in the first option?

Comment: You fix your `Constants.API_URL`. In fact, this might be a good example of where using `!` is valid because if `Constants.API_URL` doesn't give you a valid URL then you want it to crash so you can fix it early in development.

Comment: You can also start with `if var components = URLComponents(string: ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Also there is another way in swift to build string is called **interpolation** and mostly this one is used by developers.

If you using this you don't have to take your Int or another type value into string, Because is automatic take value into string.

i.e

```
let myValue = 3
let intToString = "\(myValue)" // "3"

let doubleValue = 4.5
let doubleToString = "\(doubleValue)" // "4.5"
```

So you URL will be like as below

```
let jsonUrlString = "\(Constants.API_URL)/\(Constants.PATH)/\(page)/\(Constants.NUMBER_ITEMS_PER_PAGE)"
```